# Network unstable and slow after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, 18.04, wireless, mate

I have recently upgrade from Ubuntu Mate 16.04 to 18.04 as support for 16.04 is running out. Everything went well, except I had no network after the restart. I followed a number of suggestions, the last one being:
[link](https://paulshipley.id.au/blog/coding-tips/ubuntu-16-04-to-18-04-networking-issues/)

This was met with some minor success, but my internet connection is now rather slow and it keeps dropping out every couple of minutes. I'm not really sure where to start with this problem or what information I could provide so that somebody can help me. I am not using a Lan connection, only Wifi. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Please elaborate on "I followed a number of suggestions".

Comment: Thank you for your reply guntbert. The last suggestion I followed was this one: [link](https://paulshipley.id.au/blog/coding-tips/ubuntu-16-04-to-18-04-networking-issues/)

. I tried a few others before (I can't remember which ones), and I'm not sure if they were overwritten by my last attempt or if some of these changes still hang around in the background.

Comment: You really should [edit] your question to provide additional information - comments are not a useful method for this.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I've amended the question as suggested. Thank you.